# Is the `*` symbol supported when selecting a specific row from an SQL table?

Tags: sql, operators, wildcard

I was trying to write up a model answer to a simple question about selecting a certain row from a certain table in a certain database. It went something along the lines of

```sql
select *
from table
where column = 'value';
```

However, our validation system threw a hissy fit when I tried to run this query against it. Then I remembered something about some queries not liking the wildcard symbol `*`.

My question then is, is it possible to use the symbol `*` in a query where I'm trying to access an entire row from a table?

Comment: Yes. It's called a "wildcard".

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . It is not an "operator".

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fair enough. So this is a limitation of the system, then, and not an issue with the query. Good to know.

Comment: What limitation? The query is good.

Comment: Well, there is a validation function that does the following according to the comments: "If from each column there's at least one value which is found from the submission, print error message and return False". I'm not sure what this means, so I might have to ask around a bit.